# How to Setup Plugin for web skype in Ios UIWebview

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, skype

I need to setup plugin of skype for calling someone in ios webview or WKwebview. But I cant find how to resolve this problem.Webskype.com show message install the plugin and when I tapped this button doesnt appear something.I need to setup this plugin but How ?

```
let url = URL (string: "https://web.skype.com/")
        var requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
        requestObj.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
        webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        webView.configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
        webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webView.configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/10.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_30_2) AppleWebKit/902.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/99.0.2 Safari/902.3.12"
        webView.load(requestObj)
```

Comment: Have you added this key LSApplicationQueriesSchemes into your info.plist file?

Comment: I added but still want to install plugin of skype liek that :  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
    </array>